Integratin CalHeatMap into Anguar app with SSR
I try to integrate CalHeatMap
https://cal-heatmap.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart
into my app:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgIconComponent, provideIcons } from '@ng-icons/core';
import { matWavingHandOutline } from '@ng-icons/material-icons/outline';
import CalHeatMap from 'cal-heatmap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-summary',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgIconComponent],
  templateUrl: './dashboard-summary.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dashboard-summary.component.css',
  viewProviders: [provideIcons({ matWavingHandOutline })],
})
export class DashboardSummaryComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    let cal = new CalHeatMap();
    // cal.paint({});
  }
}

but when i try to call
cal.paint({});

i got:
ReferenceError: document is not defined

that comes that:
import {Selection, root} from "./selection/index.js";

export default function(selector) {
  return typeof selector === "string"
      ? new Selection([[document.querySelector(selector)]], [document.documentElement])
      : new Selection([[selector]], root);
}

so i tried:
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import { Selection, root } from './selection/index.js';

export default function(selector) {
  // Jeśli jest to Node.js, użyj jsdom do stworzenia dokumentu
  if (typeof document === "undefined") {
    const { window } = new JSDOM();
    global.document = window.document;
    global.window = window;
  }

  return typeof selector === "string"
      ? new Selection([[document.querySelector(selector)]], [document.documentElement])
      : new Selection([[selector]], root);
}

but i still get this error.
Do you have any idea how to integrate it into the SSR app?

You can simply use afterNextRender which runs only on the browser.
Since the server does not have a document or window object.
export class DashboardSummaryComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    afterNextRender(() => {
      let cal = new CalHeatMap();
      // cal.paint({});
    });
  }
}

